# IDirect3DDevice9->clear error

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d

I am learning C++ and DirectX. I have encountered an error with `IDirect3DDevice9`. It doesn't give me an error when its compiled, but my window stops responding?

`m_pDevice3D` is global

```
m_pDevice3D->Clear(0, 0, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), 1.0f, 0);
m_pDevice3D->Present(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Is there anything I need to add in the code?

Comment: Telling us exactly what the error you've encountered is might help us guess what your problem is. Better yet would be to post a minimal complete verifiable example we could use to replicate the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Presumably you are doing this in a loop of some kind which is a hard loop of clearing. That's very likely to make any system unresponsive.

Comment: If you are new to Direct3D programming, consider using DirectX 11 instead and take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) rather than relying on an API that's 13 years old.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: Unless of course he is one of the plethora (though diminishing) of people who still uses windows XP ...

Comment: Even people targeting for Windows XP should at least be running Windows 7 :)